# Why angular.forEach context?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, foreach

I was analyzing the [`angular.forEach`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.forEach) function:

Here is the code of `angular.forEach`:

```
var values = {name: 'misko', gender: 'male'};
var log = [];

angular.forEach(values, function(value, key) {
  this.push(key + ': ' + value);
}, log);

expect(log).toEqual(['name: misko', 'gender: male']);
```

The description of context is:

> Object to become context (this) for the iterator function.

I came up with some questions:

Why use and when is useful the parameter **context**?!

Why use **this** instead the **log variable**?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the example that you provide, it is the same to use `this` or directly the `log array`. That is because `callback` used in `forEach method` and `log array` are defined in same `scope`.

However, there might be some cases in which that `callback` is defined inside a different `scope` than the `log array`. Then the call should look like the following:

```
angular.forEach(values, getNames, log);
```

In this case, we should use `this` inside the callback as it will refer to `log array` which is defined in a different `scope`.

**EDIT:**

See this **[JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ns1nsk00/1/)** and following code that shows what I explained.

```
var getNames = function(value, key) {
  this.push(key + ': ' + value);
};

var processObject = function(){
  var log = []; 
  // Now getNames callback is defined in a different 
  // scope than log
  angular.forEach(values, getNames, log);
  return log;
}

var values = {name: 'misko', gender: 'male'};
var resultArray = processObject(values);
// This gives same result as your exmple
alert(resultArray);
```

Answer (score 2):

Never used angular.forEach() but it look's pretty simple.

```
  var hello = {
      message: 'Ok'
  };

  angular.forEach([' I', ' said', ' hello'], function (value) {
      this.message += value;
  }, hello);

  console.log(hello.message);
```

1/ It will log 'Ok I said hello' so basically that 'context' param will allow you to update any object that you will refer. Use case is really broad...

2/ I think it has something to do with execution context aka. lexical environment so it meants that `this` has to be related with how angular.forEach is implemented. Just check angularjs source code.

Comment: Thanks for the attention.